# Angular & Firebase - How to update firebase: With a service or in a component?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angular-services

**What I have and what I'm trying to do**

- I have a service that get's a list of 'albums' from firebase
- I have a component that has some input fields to add a new item
- As a part of the firebase denormalisation of data, I have two nodes I want to update. 'AlbumLists' and 'AlbumDetails'
- I'm able to update to firebase with my code below (excluding the firebase suggestion at the very bottom)
- I'm aware that I'll probably need to include another service in my example. One for Album List and one for Album Summary

**Questions**

1. I've seen some example code from firebase on how to update code in multiple places and create a new key for two new nodes. However, I have no idea where this code would go in my current solution. Does it go in a component or a service?
2. If the code fits into a component is it worth having a service? (if it can work in my service, that would be nice)

> I"ve included the firebase suggested approach at the very bottom. It would be fantastic to know how to integrate that into my current structure.

**Album Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Album } from './album.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class AlbumService {
  albums: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.albums = database.list('albums');
  }

  getAlbums() {
    return this.albums;;
  }

  addAlbum(newAlbum: Album) {
    this.albums.push(newAlbum);
  }

  getAlbumById(albumId: string) {
    return this.database.object('/albums/' + albumId);
  }

  updateAlbum(localUpdatedAlbum) {
    var albumEntryInFirebase = this.getAlbumById(localUpdatedAlbum.$key);
    albumEntryInFirebase.update({
      title: localUpdatedAlbum.title,
      artist: localUpdatedAlbum.artist,
      description: localUpdatedAlbum.description      
    });
  }

}
```

**Admin.component.html - Used to add new items**

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Add New Album to Inventory</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Album Title:</label>
        <br>
        <input #newTitle>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Album Artist:</label>
        <br>
        <input #newArtist>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Album Description:</label>
        <br>
        <textarea #newDescription></textarea>
      </div>

      <button (click)="submitForm(newTitle.value, newArtist.value, newDescription.value); newTitle.value=''; newArtist.value=''; newDescription.value=''">Add</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Admin.component.ts - used to add new items**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Album } from '../album.model';
import { AlbumService } from '../album.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css'],
  providers: [AlbumService]
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    private albumService: AlbumService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submitForm(title: string, artist: string, description: string) {

    var newAlbum: Album = new Album(title, artist, description);
    this.albumService.addAlbum(newAlbum);
    console.log(newAlbum);

  }

}
```

**This is the code firebase suggest for updating information and pushing through the unique firebase key for each new node**

```js
// A post entry
var postDate = {
  author: username,
  body:body,
  title:title
}

// Get a key for a new post
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

// Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list
var udpates = {}
updates['/posts' + newPostKey] = postData;
updates['/users-posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;

return firebase.database().red().update(updates);
```

**edit:**

**admin component.ts**

The below code causes what's seen in the image. So we're getting incredibly close. Whenever i include '(key)', the following error is thrown:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'FirebaseListObservable' has no compatible call signatures.

```js
  submitForm(title: string, artist: string, description: string) {

    var newAlbum: Album = new Album(title, artist, description);
    //this.albumService.addAlbum(newAlbum);
    console.log(newAlbum);

    var albumListObject = {
      title:title,
      description:description
    }

    this.albumService.albums.push(newAlbum).then(({key}) => this.albumService.summariesObject.push(albumListObject));

  }

}
```

**Album Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Album } from './album.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class AlbumService {
  albums: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  summariesObject: FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.albums = database.list('albums');
    this.summariesObject = database.object('albumList');
  }
}
```

[image]

**Questions**

1. In my album service, will I need to have two firebase references for both albumList and Summaries? Or will they be in two different services?
2. Why is the (key) text causing an error?

Answer (score 4):

A lot of this is a matter of preference and style. Having said that, it is almost always going to be a better idea to isolate firebase-specific actions in one or more services.

However, I wonder it it's really worthwhile to define a lot of methods like `addAlbum` My personal preference is to have the service simply provide a `FirebaseListObservable`, and do the `.push` directly in the component. There may be those who find an additional layer of abstraction desirable--they may, for example, paint a scenario where you are switching from Firebase to something else. However, in practice, that's unlikely and if you did decide to do that this kind of simple abstraction layer would not help you that much anyway.

As a minor point, if you have an entire service dedicated to albums, I don't find it necessary to repeat the word "album" in all the method names. Why not just `add()`?

The standard pattern for pushing a new object onto one node and then creating a sub-node somewhere else with the same key is

```
this.albumService.list.push(albumData)
  .then(({key}) => this.albumService.summariesObject(key).update(stuff));
```

In other words, push the data to the list, generating a new key, wait for the promise to fulfill with a snapshot which will contain a key, then update a `FirebaseObjectObservable` for an object with that key inside some other node with the necessary data. It's better to try to stay within the AngularFire paradigm, although granted there are cases where you have to fall back to `firebase.database().ref` kinds of things.

Comment: Hi Torazaburo - Thank you for taking the time to respond. Much appreciated. It would be good to steer clear of .firebase.database (primarily because no matter what, I keep getting 'cannot find firebase'). If it's not too much trouble, are you able to show me an example of how your code would fit in with mine above please? (as mentioned previously, very new to all this and trying to get my head around how all the pieces fit together)

Comment: Imagine in the submit form method I want to push the title, artist and description to the firebase albums node and i want to push title and artist to the albumsList firebase node. However albums > key / albumsList > key (where both keys are the same)

Comment: Also, i do prefer your idea of having the service provide the data and doing the pushes in the component. I assume that would be the same for updates

Comment: @MetaTron yes, same holds for `update` (and `remove`).

Comment: Thanks Torazaburo. I appreciate the time. I've included an edit when attempting to integrate your changes. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I'll email you a beer or something, it feels close :)